# Connection refused to development Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost

I'm working on a Rails project and for some reason, going to `localhost:3000` showed me connection refused, not the site I'm developing. What happened?

Comment: I had this same error after I typed in `rails server -p 30000`. The extra zero in the port number was accidental, and should have been `3000`.

Answer (score 21):

Check your host file! By default, Rails only serves to 127.0.0.1. However, I had added additional entries for `localhost` into my /etc/hosts file (the system takes the last one by default). Since this wasn't 127.0.0.1 (it was the IP of my machine on my private subnet of VM's), Rails wouldn't accept the connection. You could comment out the extra lines in your host file or start the development server with `rails s -b 0.0.0.0` to allow any IP to connect to it.

Comment: rails s -b 0.0.0.0 worked for me right away on osx. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try a different port:

```
rails s -p 3001
```

You might be behind a proxy as well. That could cause issues.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem, i tried to restart the server with a different port but the problem persisted

and i found the problem in the hosts file

so try first to connect to the server with ip adress of localhost

[127.0.0.1:3000](http://127.0.0.1:3000)

Answer (score 2):

This is because rails listens only on IPv6 by default, and 127.0.0.1 is IPv4:

```
$ netstat -ant | grep 3000
tcp6   0  0  ::1.3000      *.*      LISTEN
```

Connect to ::1:3000

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to connect to local server started in WSL 2 from Windows host machine, I tried everything, then **rebooting Windows system** magically fixed the problem.